# oswald font from google fonts not works

Tags: css, web, fonts

I'm trying to design a web page, for some of the headlines I like to use `oswald` font, so inserted the following line of code in the `<head>` under the '':

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic|Oswald:400,700" 
media="screen">
```

but it does not work.
I test the page locally.

Comment: Aside from loading the font, where are the CSS rules where you applied it?

Comment: did you apply the css code? `html{font-family:"oswald"; font-size:14px;}`

Comment: Use font-family:"Oswald"

Comment: @j08691 main CSS file and .html file both reside an a folder near each other

Comment: That's fine, however in addition to linking to Google for your font file, you actually need to use the font and set some rules. For example `p{font-family: 'Oswald';}`. Just linking to the font file on Google won't magically apply itself to your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use exactly tha same name of the fonts declared on the google css:

```
html{
font-family:"Oswald";  // Capitalized Name!!!! :)
font-size:14px;
}
```

If you visit this  link - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic|Oswald:400,700- 
you´ll notice that they declare **font-family: 'Oswald';**

Comment: Try something... as you are trying this locally try to put this on the very top of your css sheet:

Comment: As you are trying this code locally, try to include at the top of your stylesheet the following import:
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic|Oswald:400,700");

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic|Oswald:400,700" media="screen"> 


<h1 style="font-family: 'Oswald'">It works</h1>
```

Comment: What's your web browser (+version n°) ?

Comment: I tested the code on opera and chrome both the latest stable version

Comment: From which country are you testing?